# Inkscape font size doesn't match that of imported figure

Tags: fonts, inkscape, font-size

I am a scientist and I like to use Inkscape to create schematic figures explaining some experiments and then to combine those figures with other figures I've created using statistical software to describe the results of those experiments. I like to use R or python to plot the results and then I specify the font sizes for all the text on the plot.

When combining images, I'd like to keep consistent font sizes, however, if I import the graphics into Inkscape and write some text in Incskape, the size of the text far from matches that of the imported graphic. The problem is illustrated in the figure below. In the red box is the axis label (12 pt Helvetica font as generated by R) and the corresponding text in Inkscape after setting to 12 pt Helvetica.

Does anyone here have a tip as to how I can make the text size match between Inkscape and an imported figure?

I have confirmed using 'Edit > Preferences > Tools > Text: Text size unit type : Point' that the unit should be points.

Thank you very much for your help.

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Can you select the text output from R when opened in Inkscape, ie. is it actual editable text?  If so, the point size should be visible in the Tool Controls Bar along the top, when you select the text with the Text Tool.

Comment: Hi Billy, no I export the figure as .tiff from R and the text can not be selected or edited after I import the figure into Inkscape (I could export as svg from R if you think that would make a difference).

Comment: Sure you could try that. Inkscape is an SVG editor after all. I Can't promise it will work though. I've never used R.

Comment: This appears to do the trick. svg images seem to be imported into inkscape at a smaller size than .tiff or .png images (by default, I realize they can be scaled up). This is curious but since the font sizes match if I import as svg, I guess the problem is solved in a way. Thanks for your help @BillyKerr

Comment: It's not that curious really.  If a raster image is large in pixel dimensions, 12pt text could be huge. If it's small in pixel dimensions, the same 12pt text could be tiny.  Remember that Inkscape is an SVG editor, and font sizes are specified withiin the SVG XML file itself, and so they will show up at the correct size in Inkscape.